# How to poll for Xvfb to be ready?

Tags: xvfb

The [Travis CI documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/gui-and-headless-browsers/) says to run `sleep 3` after starting `xvfb` to "give [it] some time to start". I couldn't find any reference to this delay in the [`man` page](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml). Is this cargo cult programming? If not, how do I **poll** rather than sleep to *guarantee* it's available?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `Xvfb` will create a Unix Domain socket for clients to connect. On my system this file socket file is created in `/tmp/.X11-unix/`. You could use `inotifywait` to listen for events in this directory. For example,

```
 $ inotifywait -e create /tmp/.X11-unix/
```

and then run `Xvfb :9` (display 9, for example). When it is ready you should see

```
/tmp/.X11-unix/ CREATE X9
```

from the `inotifywait` which will terminate. You should now be able to connect to `DISPLAY=:9`.

Comment: This would do the job on a system where I can expect proper job control, but I'm trying to do this in a Travis CI configuration file. I don't think I can rely on being able to use background jobs and wait for them to finish.

Comment: A simple `while [ ! -e /tmp/.X11-unix/X99 ]; do sleep 0.1; done` actually [did the trick](https://travis-ci.org/l0b0/graphics/builds/160870536). Marking as solved because of the path tip.

Answer (score 4):

For those who can run full-fledged scripts, another option would be to use `xdpyinfo` on desired display:

```
# Start Xvfb
sudo /usr/bin/Xvfb "${DISPLAY}" -screen 0 1280x800x24 &

# Wait for Xvfb
MAX_ATTEMPTS=120 # About 60 seconds
COUNT=0
echo -n "Waiting for Xvfb to be ready..."
while ! xdpyinfo -display "${DISPLAY}" >/dev/null 2>&1; do
  echo -n "."
  sleep 0.50s
  COUNT=$(( COUNT + 1 ))
  if [ "${COUNT}" -ge "${MAX_ATTEMPTS}" ]; then
    echo "  Gave up waiting for X server on ${DISPLAY}"
    exit 1
  fi
done
echo "  Done - Xvfb is ready!"
```

(Answer inspired by https://gist.github.com/tullmann/476cc71169295d5c3fe6).

Comment: Thanks! Just the single `xdpyinfo` line would be enough; the loop could be done in a million different ways.

Comment: Sure it can be done in many ways. Though, this snippet creates pretty-printed output that also gives you an idea of how much time it took for Xvfb to be ready. I wrote that for my own use, but realized others can benefit from that too.